No Response When Refreshing Token in Retrofit with OkHttp
I am facing an issue with the token refresh mechanism in my Android application using Retrofit and OkHttp. The following code is designed to intercept API requests, add an access token to the request headers, and refresh the token if a 401 Unauthorized response is received. However, it seems that the refresh token request is not functioning as expected.
class TokenInterceptor(private val context: Context) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val accessToken = PreferenceUtil(context).getAccessToken()
        Log.d("ApiClient", "Current token: $accessToken")

        // Add access token to header if it exists
        val requestWithToken = if (accessToken != null) {
            originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
                .build()
        } else {
            originalRequest
        }

        // Send request
        var originalResponse = chain.proceed(requestWithToken)

        if (originalResponse.code == 401) {
            // Refresh token request
            Log.e("ApiClient", "Token expired error, ${originalResponse.code}")

            val refreshToken = PreferenceUtil(context).getRefreshToken()
            Log.d("ApiClient", "Refresh token: $refreshToken")

            if (refreshToken != null) {
                Log.d("ApiClient", "Refresh token exists!")

                // Asynchronous task to request a new access token
                val newAccessToken = runBlocking {
                    reissueToken(refreshToken)
                    Log.d("ApiClient", "Why is this not working?")
                }

                newAccessToken?.let {
                    Log.d("ApiClient", "Replacing with new refresh token!")

                    val newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer $it")
                        .build()

                    originalResponse = chain.proceed(newRequest)
                }
            }
        }

        return originalResponse
    }

    private suspend fun reissueToken(refreshToken: String): String? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val apiService = ApiClient.getInstance(context).create(LogInService::class.java)
            val response = apiService.reissueToken(refreshToken)
            Log.d("ApiClient", "Receiving new response: ${response}")

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("ApiClient", "Response successful")

                response.body()?.let { tokenResponse ->
                    Log.d("ApiClient", "Token successfully renewed")
                    PreferenceUtil(context).setAccessToken(tokenResponse.accessToken)
                    PreferenceUtil(context).setRefreshToken(tokenResponse.refreshToken)
                    return@withContext tokenResponse.accessToken
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("ApiClient", "Response failed...")
                null
            }
        }
    }
}

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

ApiClient: Initializes Retrofit with OkHttpClient and adds the TokenInterceptor.
TokenInterceptor: Intercepts requests and checks for the access token. If it receives a 401 response, it attempts to refresh the token.

Logs:
"Current token: $accessToken"
"Token expired error, 401"
"Refresh token: $refreshToken"
"Refresh token exists!"


You are using too much threading. try avoid withContext(Dispatchers.IO).
Dispatchers.IO is correct for network calls but reissueToken function is in runblocking, which may not properly switch to the IO thread due to the context mismatch in runBlocking.
